# My monitor made a noise and is now dimmer - can I repair this myself?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd

I have a Samsung SyncMaster T190 LCD monitor which I've had for about 5 years. It hissed slightly then went dim (readable but the top half of the screen is less bright).

I'm pretty sure that after 5 years of service it's just got to the point where something's burned out, so my question is can I repair this myself, or should I just get a new monitor. I'm currently a student so self repair would be a better option if cost effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're a skilled electrician, this probably isn't worth your time.  There are two possibilities here - either a failing backlight assembly, which might be an easily replaceable module if you can actually find one (I'm not familiar enough with this model to say but I'd doubt it) or more likely capacitor failure, which would require locating the failed capacitor(s) and soldering in replacements.  If that's meaningless to you, then it's not something you should be trying on your own.

Comment: I thought this might be a bit too far - I'll look into finding a replacement instead - thanks.

Comment: 19" TFT panels are very cheap now - I think paying somebody to fix it would certainly cost more than just replacing it, so yeah...if you don't know what you're doing, don't sweat it.  These Samsungs are known for lousy capacitors, anyway.